# Adding classes in contact form 7 checkboxes with jquery

Tags: jquery, contact-form-7

I'm using Contact Form 7 to build a form with checkboxes. I would like to be able to assign a picture to each checkbox. This only way I see how to do this is using :before on the span wrapping the input and label but that means I need to be able to reach each checkbox with CSS.

To do so I combined a script that created an ID in the checkbox input with the input name automatically and the :has jquery selector to assign my classes to the parent and not the input.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('form.wpcf7-form input').each(function(){
      var span = $(this).parent('span');
      if(span){
        var idAttr = span.attr('id');
        $(this).attr('id',idAttr);
        span.attr('id','');
      }
      var name = $(this).attr('name');
      var type = $(this).attr('type');
      switch(type){
        case 'radio':
        case 'checkbox':
          name += '-'+$(this).attr('value');
          name = name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, '').toLowerCase(); //replace spaces with dash, remove question mark, and convert to lowercase
      }
      $(this).attr('id',name);
    });

    $( "span:has(label>input#problèmes-de-fuites)" ).addClass( "fuites" );
    $( "span:has(label>input#chaudières-radiateurs)" ).addClass( "radiateurs" );

});
```

My question is : is there a way to automate this so I don't have to manually input all the classes ? SO that the script would input the ID into the span and not the input, knowning that the span is a parent :

```
<span class="name that i get manually and want to automate">
    <label>
        <span>Checkbox title</span>
        <input name="name used by script" id="name replicated automatically">
    </label>
</span>
```

I'm a newbie in jquery so I can't figure it out myself.

Or is there a better way to do it altogether ?

Comment: Can you not just apply the class from within the contact 7 form? (within the CMS) - https://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/

Comment: No i tried it, but the class is applied to the global container or the checkboxes, and i want a different class for each input.